# prevent page loading without extension using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there any way to prevent pages from loading without extension using .htaccess file.

there is a problem with me that when i refresh/reload the page then it loads the file without extension if found.

i've only the code in .htaccess file is

> RewriteEngine On
> ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Please somebody help me to figure out from this.

Comment: You're explanation of your problem is not clear. Put an example of your issue and then what's happening  with your code.

Comment: [link](http://luxusdrive.ch)
please visit the url then click on any menu and after that refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you load and handle all links with ajax.

so you should rewrite all request to index.php which you can use this in your htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

also in your javascript file you should check the url after the page has loaded. if url contains a particular address and exist call the page by ajax or load a 404 if not exist.

**Edited Try this htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: this is not working for me...
nothing change, i wanna prevent pages to autoload when refresh, if found in directory...
what i want that on every refresh index page should be run...

Comment: @john The second one would work. apache handle the htaccess it contains  condition and rule. which here we say if the request is not a existing file or directory redirect it on index.php

Comment: let me tell you in breif
but first of all please take a look [link](http://luxusdrive.com)
and refresh the page after click any menu

Comment: so sorry
it's .ch not .com

Comment: are you sure you have rewrite module working on your hosting?

Comment: yeah
damn sure... cause when i enter an incorrect url it redirects to index page in a weird style.

Comment: I even made a sample project in my local with your javascript codes and this htaccess and it works fine. it seems there are some other rules in apache or somewhere which affect. and better to see your index.php code maybe

Comment: Thanks for your precious time @Gholizadeh ,
it works fine for me too on local :( ...

Comment: if its a child root in hosting check general apache settings or parents directory settings